# Linking Header File with Main.Cpp file in Codeblocks

Tags: opencv, c++11, codeblocks

I am trying to use codeblocks to compile the code available [here](http://www.vision.ee.ethz.ch/~gfanelli/downloads/head_pose_estimation.tgz)

The thing is every time I try to build and run, I run into the following error:

|`/.../head_pose_estimation/opencv2/core/core.hpp|48|fatal error:       opencv2/core.hpp: No such file or directory`

Does anyone know how I can fix this? Thank you!

Comment: Re-download opencv 2.4.10 and extract it again.  There should be a opencv2/core.hpp and an opencv2/core/core.hpp.  The former just includes the latter, but you should have both.

Comment: I keep seeing only one opencv2/opencv.hpp and another opencv/cxcore.hpp. I downloaded it from github.com/itseez. Do you have a reference website where I can download the one you are talking about?

Comment: http://opencv.org/downloads.html.  If you get just the source from GitHub, you have to build it.  So, get the pre-built (and pre-organized source).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have the pre-built (compiled) version of OpenCV, what you currently have are the source files. If you want to do something special with OpenCV (Target/GPU SUpport etc) then you will need to build the framework using an appropriate guide.

If however you simply want to use OpenCV in the most common way then download the pre-built libraries from the [OpenCV.org](http://opencv.org/downloads.html) website.

NOTE:

If you are using OpenCV with MinGW compiler, I do not remember if the pre-built is actually pre-built for MinGW. (I dont think they do) In this case you will HAVE to built the libraries. You can find a guide [here](http://kevinhughes.ca/tutorials/opencv-install-on-windows-with-codeblocks-and-mingw/)